# C++: closure to pass member function as normal function pointer

Tags: c++, arduino, atmega

I'm trying to call a member function of an external library which takes a function pointer as a parameter:

```
Timer::every(unsigned long period, void (*callback)(void));
```

But unfortunately the parameter I want to pass is a member function:

```
void MyClass::the_method_i_want_to_pass(void);
```

Since I'm programming for the ATMega under Arduino (AVR) there is just limited support of c++11. My first approach raises a type error:

```
void MyClass::the_method_i_want_to_pass() {...}

MyClass::MyClass() {
    // constructor

    Timer *timer = new Timer();
    timer->every(500, [this](){this->the_method_i_want_to_pass();})
}
```

Compiler Output:

> warning: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
>
> error: no matching function for call to ‘Timer::every(int, MyClass::MyClass()::__lambda0)’

1. Are there other/better solutions?
2. Concerning my current approach: (How) is it possible to pass a reference to a lambda when a function pointer is required?
3. How can I find out if Arduino/AVR supports these lambdas (see "warning")?

Comment: Does your compiler support `std::mem_fn`, its c++11 though

Comment: Using the [StandardCplusplus Library](https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus) there's a port that seems similar.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. It's like saying, "my wife wants me to bring home tomatoes. I have a box of nails and a loaf of bread. 1. Are there any better solutions? 2. How can I please my wife? 3. How can I find a wife that accepts nails and bread as tomatoes?"

Comment: I don't get your point @KerrekSB. In my eyes it's a well defined question towards the limitation of a thirdparty library.

Comment: @PenthousePauper: Well, you have a function that requires an X, and you have a Y, which is not an X. Member functions aren't functions. You cannot *call* member functions. So I sense a massive conceptual misunderstanding here.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Right, i deal with an architecture strongly relying on OOP on one hand and a library with only functional support on the other hand. My approach to connect those two was to encapsulate the OOP scope into a lambda function (closure) as it is done since Star Wars IV. But you may want to enlighten me now.

Comment: A function has no state. A member function can only be invoked on a class instance, which contains state for the member function. It's just not the same. There's no room in your callback API to fit the state that is needed to invoke the member function.

Comment: Exactly that's what the closure is for... encapsulating the scope / state into a function. What would be your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is your `Timer` library is poorky written: it should take `void(*)(void*), void*` at the least.

Without a pvoid or equivalent, you cannot pass any state other than the address in execution code to run the procedure at.  As a method also rewuires a `this` pointer, you are out of luck.

Now, if your instance of `MyClass` is a singleton, you can get `this` from somewhere else.

Failing that, you need to make your own global state that lets you map from a particular callback to some state.  If you have a limited number of `MyClass` and other consumers of `Timer`, you can have a few fixed functiins, and have them store their extra state globally.

This is all a hack.  What follows is worse.

Write a dynamic library with some global state, and a `void()` interface.  When you add a callback, duplicate that dynamic library, modify its global state at runtime, write it out as a differently named library, load it, and pass the pure callback function to your `Timer` class.

Or do the equvalent without a library by manually writing machine code and marking pages as execuable.

These are all poor solutions.  Which leads me to a good one: find a better `Timer`.  If they screwed up something that simple, the rest of the library is probably bad as well.

Comment: thanks for your response! guess i'll start with a hack til i can replace it with something better.